# sed with = as delimiter

Tags: text-processing, sed

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to use `sed` to cut text before a certain delimiter.

I'm receiving output from `echo` that returns something similar to:

```
valueA=TEXT
```

I would like to have `sed` cut the text before `=` and leaving only TEXT.

Any tips on how it can be done?

Comment: It's not entirely clear where the output comes from but the right tool for this job is either `cut` or _parameter expansion_ (not to say that `sed` can't do it...)

Comment: My bad @don_crissti! Output is coming from echo. I'll try and edit OP.

Comment: **AWK** `awk -F= '{print $2}`  **SED**:  `sed -e s/^[^=]*=//`

Comment: Thank you @Archemar! sed example worked exactly as intended!

Comment: I am not found of cut, but cut should do to.

Comment: i concur with @don_crissti - in a case as simple as this, " ...| cut -d = -f 2- " is much simpler - to type at least

Comment: How is `echo` getting the text? If it is already in a shell variable, just use parameter expansion: `foo='valueA=text'; echo "${foo#=}"`.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `cut` :

```
cut -d= -f2- <<< "$yourvar"
```

or

```
some_command | cut -d= -f2-
```

- `-d=` sets the delimiter to `=`
- `-f2-` takes the second field and all the following ones

Answer (score 5):

From @Archemar's comment, which should probably have been an answer:

```
sed -e s/^[^=]*=//
```

From @Baard Kopperud's comment, the `sed` command can be explained as:

Substitute lines (s/) beginning (^) with any number of characters (*) except "=" ([^=]) followed by an equation-sign (=) with nothing (//). This will remove anything from the beginning of the line, to and including the equal-sing - leaving just what comes after the "=". You need the "[^=]*" in case there are multiple equal-signs... you just want to delete up to the first one. If you just used ".*", then you'd cut up to and including the last equal-sign, as regular expressions "wish" to be as long as possible, and starting as far to the left as possible.

Comment: Well, at least do explain sed command.

Comment: Substitute lines (s/) beginning (^) with any number of characters (\*) except "=" ([^=]) followed by an equation-sign (=) with nothing (//).  This will remove anything from the beginning of the line, to and including the equal-sing - leaving just what comes after the "=".  You need the "[^=]\*" in case there are multiple equal-signs... you just want to delete up to the first one.  If you just used ".\*", then you'd cut up to and including the last equal-sign, as regular expressions "wish" to be as long as possible, and starting as far to the left as possible.

Comment: @BaardKopperud, just edit the explanation into the answer.  Comments are ephemeral.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm receiving output from `echo`

If you're forming that `echo` from a variable, you can use the shell's built-in string manipulation capabilities:

```
# Instead of value=$(echo "$var" | cut -d= -f2-)
value=${var#*=}
```

The `*=` is just a glob-style pattern, where `*` matches anything. The `#` indicates that the pattern matches a prefix to be removed from the variable.

This will ultimately be faster and more reliable than piping from `echo`, as it avoids the trouble `xpg_echo` can land you in (as well as other parsing quirks of `echo`), and it avoids a fork.

You can also get the key using this method:

```
key=${var%%=*}
```

Note that `%%` is used rather than `%` to match greedily. With that, it won't be tripped up by any potential `=`-signs in the value.

The syntax is documented in `man bash`, under `Parameter Expansion`:

> ```
>    ${parameter#word}
>    ${parameter##word}
>           Remove matching prefix pattern.  The word is expanded to produce
>           a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  If the pattern matches
>           the  beginning of the value of parameter, then the result of the
>           expansion is the expanded value of parameter with  the  shortest
>           matching  pattern  (the ``#'' case) or the longest matching pat‐
>           tern (the ``##'' case) deleted.  If parameter is  @  or  *,  the
>           pattern  removal operation is applied to each positional parame‐
>           ter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.  If param‐
>           eter  is  an array variable subscripted with @ or *, the pattern
>           removal operation is applied to each  member  of  the  array  in
>           turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.
>
>    ${parameter%word}
>    ${parameter%%word}
>           Remove matching suffix pattern.  The word is expanded to produce
>           a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  If the pattern matches
>           a  trailing portion of the expanded value of parameter, then the
>           result of the expansion is the expanded value of parameter  with
>           the  shortest  matching  pattern (the ``%'' case) or the longest
>           matching pattern (the ``%%'' case) deleted.  If parameter  is  @
>           or  *,  the  pattern  removal operation is applied to each posi‐
>           tional parameter in turn, and the  expansion  is  the  resultant
>           list.   If  parameter is an array variable subscripted with @ or
>           *, the pattern removal operation is applied to  each  member  of
>           the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.
> ```